How to encourage horizontal growth for my rubber tree plant
I’ve grown this plant from a tiny sprout almost 4 years ago. But it’s only grown up without branching out. I’m afraid to cut off any leaves in the event that it doesn’t lead to sprouting, however, I’d like the plant to get a bit taller before chopping the top. Appreciate insights.

This plant is Ficus elastica and you can see a good picture of a mature plant that has been cut back and branched out here.
To get your plant to branch out you can:

move to the highest light area you have
cut back anywhere on the main stem at least six inches above the soil
reduce watering until new growth appear

These plants are tough and readily bud out of old wood.  As long as they are not overwatered or kept in really low light they will grow quickly.
